# SSRS CountRows shows duplicated number

Tags: reporting-services

The dataset looks like

```
Time  Type
2018   a
2019   b
2013   c
2017   a
2018   a
```

I want to get number of rows according to Type.
So I have add Type under Row Groups called `GroupByType`

[image]

In the expression, I have used

```
=CountRows()
```

but it end of with number of 1s according to Type,

```
a 1
  1
  1
b 1
c 1
```

But when I use

```
=CountRows("GroupByType")
```

it shows:

```
a  3
   3
   3
b  1
c  1
```

How can I get the following structure?

```
a  3
b  1
c  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Row Groups section you need to remove the details section: =(Type)